# How do I pass current date range from Fullcalendar to the JSON function which retrieves data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I use fullcalendar eventsources function, to get events data from db:

```
eventSources: getSources()
```

where getSources is

```
getSources(){
 var mysources = {
   mysourceone:{
                url: YOUR URL TO GET JSON,
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{
                //SOME DATA YOU MIGHT PASS                   },
                 cache: false,
                 color: '#C1272D',
                 textColor: 'white'
                 }
              }
  return [mysources.mysourceone];
}
```

My question is, how do I pass currently selected date range from fullcalendar to the getSources function?

I would like to retrieve from db only relevant data to selected dates! Currently this function returns data from db regardless of selected date range.

Comment: YOu want to fetch new data form server based on your selection in calendar ? is that what you asking ?

eventsources: Is used to load initially events from server. 

If you want to have a date limit you can pass in data:{} like i told you in the other post....

If you want to select the calendar and after that load other events to calendar, this will not suit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function getSources() must return an array of functions, rather than literal data. Each of those functions will be called with these parameters:

```
yourfunction( start, end, timezone, callback )
```

Fullcalendar will fill in the dates you're looking for in start and end.

Tip: if you limit your search in DB to `start` and `end`, you will miss events that start before the `start`, but end somewhere between `start` and `end`. E.g. you want to display part of last week's event in this week, if the event stretches across the weeks' borders. So I actually expand the period between `start` and `end` by subtracting 2 months from `start` and adding 2 months to `end`. This way you can have events up to two months long which are guaranteed to be visible.

Comment: Now I have find the was how to pass date range to the ajax script, which returns the data within my function, but how do I replace fixed data range with dates from current view in the calendar?      

     data:{
         st:'2016-08-19',et:'2016-08-24'
      },